# How to remove all numbers from a file name or a string - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python script that will walk through all of the directories within the `Test Folder`(in this case) and will remove all numbers at the **beginning** of each of the file names. So my **question** is how would I modify my script in order to remove numbers from the whole file name? Not just the beginning or the end of it.

Thanks,
Alex

```py
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("Test Folder", topdown=True):
    for name in files:
        if (name.startswith("01") or name.startswith("02") or name.startswith("03") or name.startswith("04") or name.startswith("04") or name.startswith("05") or name.startswith("06") or name.startswith("07") or name.startswith("08") or name.startswith("09") or name[0].isdigit()):
            old_filepath = (os.path.join(root, name))
            _, new_filename = name.split(" ", maxsplit=1)
            new_filepath = (os.path.join(root, new_filename))
            os.rename(old_filepath, new_filepath)
```

Comment: Sidenote: Replace your `not_usful` varibale with a `_`. This will dump the variable instantly.

Comment: It's time to learn about regular expressions.

Comment: @AlexBelyaev Yes I know

Comment: Your `if` statement can be simplified to `if any(name.startswith(("%2d" % i) for i in range(1, 10)) or name[0].isdigit())`

Comment: @zondo - A regex would be shorter than that. Some may consider "shorter" as "simplified"

Comment: @zondo When I used `if any(name.startswith(("%2d" % i) for i in range(1, 10)) or name[0].isdigit()):` I got `TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not generator` I do not know what the problem is?

Comment: A word of warning: If you run this script without further checks, it might overwrite files with each other if their original filenames only differ in numbers.

Comment: @tobias_k Yes that is a great point

Comment: @Alex I mis-typed.  It should be `if any(name.startswith("%2d" % i) for i in range(1, 10)) or name[0].isdigit():`

Comment: @zondo What does `"%2d"` do in `if any(name.startswith("%2d" % i) for i in range(1, 10)) or name[0].isdigit():`

Comment: It makes `4` " 4" and `45` "45".  It's a good thing you asked, though, because it doesn't quite do what you want.  I'm sorry to cause so much trouble.  You want "04" not " 4", so use "%02d".

Comment: @zondo Is there any documentation on those so I can learn more about them? In other words, what is `"%02d"` called?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) you can find a lot of information about strings.  Examples of string formatting are [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples)

Comment: @zondo What does `if any(name.startswith("%2d" % i) for i in range(1, 10)) or name[0].isdigit():` look like in a normal if statement?

Comment: @Alex From the docs: `any(iterable) -> bool  Return True if bool(x) is True for any x in the iterable.`  The iterable is a check for `name` starting with a certain string for each number in `range(1, 10)`.  The result is that it checks to see if `name` starts with any two-digit number in `range(1, 10)`.  ("%2d" makes a one-digit number two characters by putting a space before it.  That is why I told you to use "%02d", because that puts a 0 before a one-digit number.  That part is unnecessary, though, because if `name` starts with any of those numbers, `name[0].isdigit()` will return `True`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :-}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use regular expression, particularly [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> import re
>>> filename = '12name34with56numbers78in9it.txt'
>>> re.sub(r'\d', '', filename)
'namewithnumbersinit.txt'
```

This replaces everything that matches the `\d` pattern, i.e. that is a number, with `''`, i.e. nothing.

If you want to protect the extension, it get's more messy. You have to split the extension from the string, replace numbers in the first part, then join the extension back on. `os.path.splitext` can help you with that:

```
>>> filename = '12name34with56numbers78in9it.mp3'
>>> name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
>>> re.sub(r'\d+', '', name) + ext
'namewithnumbersinit.mp3'
```

Comment: Just curious, would `\d+` be beneficial at all?

Comment: @cricket_007 Good question... you would have fewer, longer matches, and fewer replacements. `\d+` might be a bit faster, but I did not time it. EDIT: Did time it. In my very simple example, `\d+` is about 10% faster.

Comment: It might be worth protecting file extensions; it would do bad things to your .mp3 collection ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
filename = "this2has8numbers323in5it"
filename = "".join(char for char in filename if not char.isdigit())
```

No imports necessary.

Comment: Think you meant `if not char.isdigit()`

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes I did, but I come too late to see what I had.  What was it?

Comment: if not filename...  you can see the edit history if you click the editted by link

Comment: @zondo What does `char for char in filename if not char.isdigit()` look like in a classic conditional format, in other words, what is `char for char in filename if not char.isdigit()` in a normal block format look like???

Comment: @zondo Sorry for all of the questions.

Comment: @Alex To put it in a normal block, you would need something like `chars = []  for char in filename: if not char.isdigit(): chars.append(char) filename = "".join(chars)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

def rename_files():
    # Get files names from the directory
    files_names = os.listdir(" file r directory path")

    saved_dir = os.chdir(files_name)

    # To get cutrrent working directiry name
     print os.getcwd() # This is to verify whether you are in correct path

    for file_name in files_names:
        os.rename(file_name,file_name.translate(None,'0123456789'))    
        # Above translate function remove all the number from file name
rename_files()
```